# Return JavaScript age calculation to screen

Tags: javascript, html, date-arithmetic

Using HTML 5, CSS, JavaScript and JQuery to create a web application.

I have used the new Date() function in order to generate today's date.
I have also used the JQuery "datepicker" function in order to allow the user to select their DOB. These are both working perfectly.

What I want is for the age to be calculated when the DOB has been selected.
I have included a function to calculate the age which relies on the date and DOB but cannot get it to return the number to the screen.  This can be seen below.

```
<tr>
    <td>Age:</td>
    <!--td><input type="text" id="age" /></td-->
    <td> 
            <script type = "text/javascript">
        var date = document.getElementById("adDate").value
        var dob = document.getElementById("datepicker").value
        var pattern = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/
        if (pattern. test(dob)) {
            var currentYear = date.getFullYear()
            var birthYear = date.getFullYear()
            var age = currentYear - birthYear
            document.write(age)
        } 
        </script>
    <td>
</tr>
```

I have search for solutions on-line but just get the basic JavaScript age calculation. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks.

I tried to apply some changes so to no avail. 
I have updated the JS which is shown below.

```
var date = document.getElementById("adDate").value
var dob = document.getElementById("datepicker").value
var pattern = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/
if (pattern. test(dob)) {
    var currentYear = new Date(date).getFullYear()
    var birthYear = new Date(dob).getFullYear()
    var age = currentYear - birthYear

    var spanAge = document.getElementById("age")
    spanAge.innerHTML = age
}
```

And also the HTML.

```
<tr>
    <td>Age:</td>
    <td><span id="age"></span></td>
</tr>
```

It must be something to do with using the datepicker to generate the DOB.  I tried applying an onSelect function but nothing seems to work.

Any other advice?

Comment: birthYear should not use date. You should also create Date objects with the value from the UI elements.

Comment: You need an event to trigger the calculation. I would reccomend using onSelect http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect for the Datepicker

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for your fast replies!

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you create a valid Date object, you can pass it the value from the UI elements:

```
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()            
var birthYear = new Date('5/6/1987').getFullYear()             
var age = currentYear - birthYear
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code:

```
var currentYear = new Date(date).getFullYear()
var birthYear = new Date(dob).getFullYear()
```

Restore your table cell:

```
<td><span id="age"></span></td>
```

And, instead of document.write use this:

```
// document.write(age) // Remove this line.
var spanAge = document.getElementById("age")
spanAge.innerHTML = age
```

Here a simulation:

http://jsfiddle.net/dEaae/1/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your code is only subtracting the full year of birth from the current year.  So, If I was born on Dec. 31 10 years ago, I would be listed as the same age as someone born Jan. 1st of the same year, even though they are likely a full year older

Answer (score -2):

You should pick a html eleement in which to display the result

Ex:

```
            <div id = "printHere"></div>

             <tr>
<td>Age:</td>
<!--td><input type="text" id="age" /></td-->
<td> 
        <script type = "text/javascript">
         //assuming you have "age" here

          //using jquery
          $("#printHere").html(age);
    } 
    </script>
<td>
```

Comment: date.getFullYear() is not a function, you need a Date object